# Labels and Variables in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, label, 64-bit, x86-64, att

Consider I have a label in assembly (at&t syntax, x86-64) like this:

```
test_tabel:
    mov test_label,%eax #1
    mov (test_label),%eax #2
    mov $test_label,%eax #3
```

Can someone kindly tell what's the difference between these three as I saw them a lot but can't really understand what each really means (address, value etc...)

Now in case I have a variable in .data section (let's suppose it's of size int ie 4 bytes) what's the difference between those 3:

```
mov var,%eax #4
mov var,%eax #5
mov $var,%eax #6
```

Comment: Didn't you mean your 5th line to read `mov (var), %eax`, with the parenthesis. You've made it identical to the 4th line!

Comment: Note that `mov $test_label,%eax` may be a problem, since an address is generally 64 bits and you're loading it into a 32-bit register.  Normally `lea test_label(%rip), %rax` should be used instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) and (2) are identical and load 4 bytes from memory at `test_label` into `eax`.  (3) loads the address of `test_label` into `eax`.

A variable is just a label, so there's nothing special going on with your second set of examples.

(4) and (5) are identical to (1) and (2) in behaviour, (6) is identical to (3) in behaviour.

Comment: are you sure? I learnt $ means address...

Comment: Please note it's at&t syntax x64

Comment: @Dan I did say that “(3) loads the *address* of test_label into eax.”  What did you expect?

Comment: You answer doesn't make sense here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69486268/order-in-data-in-x64-assembly